# GDB debugging warnings

Tags: qt, gdb, libc

When I try to debug my core-dump via gdb either in Qt or directly from terminal, it gives me bunches of warnings like below. Therefore my backtrace is not working properly.

> warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
>
> warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
>
> warning: Could not load shared library symbols for ).
> Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Is this because my executable built without debugging symbols or is the problem about glibc? Do you have any solution to fix this?

Comment: It looks like gdb can't find the libraries mentioned. If they are shared libraries you might check to see if the search path is set in the environment so it can locate them. When you create a terminal session it might not inherit the same environment as run time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this because my executable built without debugging symbols or is the problem about glibc?

This has nothing to do with your executable.

GDB needs a version of `libthread_db.so.1` that matches your `libpthread.so.0`, and is not finding such version.

Probable causes (from most to least probable):

- You have stripped libpthread.so.0 (*don't* do that).
- You've upgraded your glibc, but the upgrade was incomplete and did not update `libthead_db.so.1`
- You are using some kind of cross-compilation environment, and really *do* need to `set solib-search-path` or `set libthread-db-search-path` such that GDB can find a matching `libthread_db.so.1`

You can see which versions of `libthread_db` GDB is trying with `set debug libthread-db 1`.

Comment: The information about not stripping libthread helped us solve our problem with generating dump file from gdb, resulting in a dump with only one of our threads