# Analyze Linux core dump on different machine: threads and shared libs

Tags: gdb, coredump, postmortem-debugging

Here is the [sad story](https://forums.thedarkmod.com/index.php?/topic/21060-mission-downloader-issue/&do=findComment&comment=465301):

1. I built an executable `thedarkmod.x64` on my machine, with debug symbols moved off to a separate `thedarkmod.x64.debug` file.
2. A user experienced a crash on this executable, while running it under gdb. She saved core dump `core.1600` using `generate-core-file` gdb command.
3. I downloaded this core file and opened it by starting `gdb ./thedarkmod.x64 core.1600`.
4. I switch between threads and run `bt` command, but I see some trash instead of proper stack traces.

Note: the user has my `thedarkmod.x64.debug` file, and when she runs `bt` just before saving the core dump, she sees meaningful stack trace.

---

When I start gdb on core dump, I see many warning messages like:

- Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available
- warning: .dynamic section for "libXXX.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364781/gdb-debugging-warnings), the first warning seems to imply that unless I have the same version of `libthread_db.so.1` as the one on the machine where core dump was saved, I cannot see anything useful in multithreaded program. I asked the user to find this file and give it to me, but it did not help. Then I asked to provide `libpthread.so.0` file too, and after some struggling with `set solib-search-path`, `set sysroot`, `set auto-load safe-path`, and `set libthread-db-search-path` I managed to get this warning replaced with "Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled", but stack traces were still wrong.

So the questions are:

1. Is there a way to properly inspect core dumps generated on Linux machine with vastly different environment? I mean different kernel, pthreads, glibc, etc. Is there anywhere detailed instructions on how to achieve that?
2. Is there any gdb command like `generate-core-file includecode`, which would embed all the code including the necessary .so libs into the core file, so that I could open it on my machine without additional hassle?

At the current moment, I have to admit that Linux core dumps are pretty useless to me, since I am not ready to create a new Linux VM for every core dump submitted.

---

**UPDATE:** I managed to obtain proper stack trace.

1. The solution provided in the "duplicate question" did not work for me. No solib-related setting was enough, only `set sysroot` helped.
2. In my particular case, the stack trace ended inside `free` function of libc. Gdb could not walk through its call stack, supposedly because it was compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer` just like most libraries. Making sure gdb loads `libc.so.6` obtained from the user's machine helped.

Here is the full list of gdb commands which I use (each of them is necessary to make things work, except for `bt` of course):

```py
# note: all the .so files obtained from user machine must be put into local directory.
#
# most importantly, the following files are necessary:
#   1. libthread_db.so.1 and libpthread.so.0: required for thread debugging.
#   2. other .so files are required if they occur in call stack.
#
# these files must also be renamed exactly as the symlinks
# i.e. libpthread-2.28.so should be renamed to libpthread.so.0

# load executable file
file ./thedarkmod.x64

# force gdb to forget about local system!
# load all .so files using local directory as root
set sysroot .

# drop dump-recorded paths to .so files
# i.e. load ./libpthread.so.0 instead of ./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
set solib-search-path .
# disable damn security protection
set auto-load safe-path /

# load core dump file
core core.6487

# print stacktrace
bt
```

Comment: You probably need the same version of all shared libraries the program uses, not just libthread_db.so.

Comment: @ssbssa, I don't understand why I need them if I don't want to debug them. I only want to see stacktrace of each thread with proper names of functions from my executable, I don't care if library functions will be shown as meaningless addresses.

Comment: But it will not be able to get the correct return address of any functions of these libraries, so the stacktrace from them on will not make much sense.

Comment: @ssbssa, the concept of frame pointers allows to fetch call stack without having code or debug symbols. That's how things work on normal platforms, and I seriously doubt Linux x64 is any different in this regard.

Comment: So you built this application with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`?

Comment: @ssbssa, Yes, `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is included in compilation options of the application. Do you suppose that the glibc was compiled with -fomit-frame-pointers, so I cannot see call stack because the crash is in malloc, and the user can see it because she has debug symbols of that version of glibc?...

Comment: Yes, I think that's very likely.

Comment: @ssbssa, your idea was correct. By taking libc.so.6 from user and more f_cking with gdb commands, I managed to get proper stacktrace.